# How to set proxy settings to view YouTube from China in Ubuntu?

Tags: proxy

I am new for Ubuntu OS, now I am in China.

I cannot open YouTube so I want to know which proxy setting will allow to view YouTube videos?

Answer (score 1):

The specific proxy, there are many.

Personally, I would recommend Tor for firewall jumping

https://www.torproject.org/

https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en

Download the proper version that suits you (32bit or 64bit). I recommend using this link first.
Enjoy proxyjumping!